# Element Background Image DataURL

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to get a callback on `background-image` is loaded with a base 64 `DataURL`. I can cache this with image `src` attribute, but with data url ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

Should work the way it usually does:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/  png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh.......";
image.onload = function() {
    //image was loaded
};
```

Caching by the browser is of course disabled for Base64 strings, that's why it's normally only used for small images, like icons and stuff.

You can convert images to Base64 online here : http://base64img.com/#encode

Note that some browsers can have limitations on size for Base64.

Comment: It's nice but that was not my question. Need the load event for the background-image. I was asking about the image src loading in relation to cache the image.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that style.BackgroundImage property do not set the value asynchronously. So my problem is solved.